# Check all pictureBoxes in pictureBox Array - Checkers Game?

Tags: c#, loops, picturebox

Hey guys I'm working on a Checkers Game. I have this method that declares the winner, I was hoping if there was a way to do this using a loop. At the moment it works just fine :), but I've had to hard code it instead of using a logic.

```
public void checkWinner() {
  if (pictureBoxs[0].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[2].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[4].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[6].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[9].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[11].Image != bc &&
    pictureBoxs[13].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[15].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[16].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[18].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[20].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[22].Image != bc &&
    pictureBoxs[25].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[27].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[29].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[31].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[32].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[34].Image != bc &&
    pictureBoxs[36].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[38].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[41].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[43].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[45].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[47].Image != bc &&
    pictureBoxs[48].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[50].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[52].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[54].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[57].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[59].Image != bc &&
    pictureBoxs[61].Image != bc && pictureBoxs[63].Image != bc) {
    MessageBox.Show("White is the winner!");

  } else if (pictureBoxs[0].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[2].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[4].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[6].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[9].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[11].Image != wc &&
    pictureBoxs[13].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[15].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[16].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[18].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[20].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[22].Image != wc &&
    pictureBoxs[25].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[27].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[29].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[31].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[32].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[34].Image != wc &&
    pictureBoxs[36].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[38].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[41].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[43].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[45].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[47].Image != wc &&
    pictureBoxs[48].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[50].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[52].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[54].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[57].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[59].Image != wc &&
    pictureBoxs[61].Image != wc && pictureBoxs[63].Image != wc) {
    MessageBox.Show("Black is the winner!");
  }
}
```

I cannot use for loop from 0 to 63 as `pictureBoxs[1]` or `pictureBoxs[3]` is set to nothing and it produces an error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ to grab only the `PictureBox`s that are *not* `null`, then test the value of `Image`:

```
if (pictureBoxs.Where(p => p != null).All(p => p.Image != bc))
    MessageBox.Show("White is the winner!");
else if (pictureBoxs.Where(p => p != null).All(p => p.Image != wc))
    MessageBox.Show("Black is the winner!");
```

Comment: I tried it but it produces NullReferenceException. I think it's the same issue like i pointed, it's trying to check for example pictureBoxs[1] or pictureBoxs[62], which are not set to anything.

Comment: Accepted answer +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an 'IsWinner' function like this:

```
    private bool IsWinner(Image opponent)
    {
        foreach (PictureBox box in pictureBoxes)
        {
            if (
                (box.Image != null)
                && (box.Image == opponent)
                )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Then call it like so:

```
        if (IsWinner(wc))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Black is the winner!");
        }
        else if (IsWinner(bc))
        {
             MessageBox.Show("White is the winner!");
        }
```